# assign multiple values to a matrix in c#

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

is there a way to have a matrix that stores an int and a boolean at the same time?

Imagine having a matrix: `matrix[x, y]`

Now, is it somehow possible to do something like this?
`matrix[2, 1] = 5, true`
`matrix[1, 5] = 2, false`

The matrix simply stores an int **and** a boolean value at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C# 7.0 introduced a simple syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) for *tuples* to store multiple values in one matrix element:

```
var matrix = new (int, bool)[10, 10];

matrix[2, 1] = (5, true);
matrix[1, 5] = (2, false);
```

The example creates a 2D array of 10 times 10 tuples.
Here, `(int, bool)` defines tuples which consist of an `int` and a `bool` value.

It would be simpler to use two matrices in parallel, one for the integers and one for the bool values.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!